# How to use a ListViewItem to navigate instead of a button? WPF, Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, listview, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.micro for navigation between views. When I use  buttons to pass between views it works. But I would like to use ListView to navigate.

This is working;

```
 <Button x:Name="OpenOverview"/>
```

But this one is not working;

```
<ListViewItem
                   x:Name="OpenOverview"
                    Width="60"
                    Height="40"
                    Margin="0,5,0,0"
                    Padding="0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.375"
                    ToolTipService.Placement="Right"
                    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Overview">
```

In my MainViewModel, I have ;

```
 public void OpenStorage()
    {
        ActivateItem(new StorageViewModel());
    }
```

How can I bind this to LİstView Item like I did for Button?

Comment: Have you tried binding SelectedItem on ListView, and execute some navigation code in setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to Navigate depending on the selection in the ListView. You could do using `Selected` Event for the purpose.

```
<ListViewItem  cal:Message.Attach="[Event Selected]=[Action OpenOverview]">Overview Page</ListViewItem>
```

Please do remember to add following reference while using the `cal:Message.Attach`

```
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
```